# Fix screwed column data in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas DataFrame with screwed column data.

DataFrame column names: name, city, education, price, country

DataFrame normal row looks like this:

```
|name|city|education|price|country|
|----|----|---------|-----|-------|
|'[{"name":"andrew"}, {"name":"jack"}]'|'[{"city":"New York"}]'| '[{"education":"high"}]'|'[{"price":"low"}, {"price":"moderate"}]'| '[{"country": "US"}, {"country":"Canada"}]'|
|'[{"name":"bob"}, {"name":"jhon"}}]'|'[{"city":"Chicago"}, {"city":"Mexico"}]'|'[{"education":"low"}, {"education":"high"}]'| '[{"price":"high"}, {"price":"moderate"}]'|'[{"country": "Mexico"}, {"country":"Italy"}]'|
|'[{"name":"Sean"}]'|'[{"city":"Acapulco"}]'|'[{"education":"high"}]'| '[{"price":"low"}|{"price":"high"}]'|'[{"country": "US"}]'|
```

But some rows are crewed and look like this:

```
|name|city|education|price|country|
|----|----|---------|-----|-------|
|'[{"education":"high"}]'|'[{"city":"New York"}]'|'[{"name":"andrew"}, {"name":"jack"}}]'|'[{"country": "US"}, {"country":"Canada"}]'| '[{"price":"low"}, {"price":"moderate"}]'|
|'[{"city":"New York"}]'|'[{"education":"school"}]'|'[{"name":"bob"}, {"name":"jack"}}]'|'[{"country": "US"}]'|'[{"price":"low"}]'|
```

What is the best way to return bad row cells to its places?

Comment: Can you format the columns and data better as well as provide sample data/code that you have tried?

Comment: Please provide the dataframe in a form that is readable (now just lists of strings). And what exactly is _screwed_ in those rows?

Comment: I created table, which should be more representative with a couple more rows.

The problem is, for example, some cells that should be in education column are in city column for some rows

Comment: Seems like it may be symptom of imported data structure or format.  Have you checked for missing delimeters in your source table? Tried different delkmeters?

Comment: Yes, it was caused by bad import, but it is what it is and I need to fix it. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Please update your question to include your last comment.  In order to help in your data import, we need to see what you are importing and what process or code you use to import it.

Comment: It was not my import, I just got file after bad import and need to fix it